# Databricks job cannot find python library imported in the cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, mysql-connector, pymysql

I am trying to run a cron job on my notebook and I get an "no module found" error. When I look at the job logs this is the full error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2307930105977041> in <module>
      1 from __future__ import print_function
      2 import sys
----> 3 import pymysql

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

This library has been installed to my cluster that I am running the job from and the notebook that uses this library runs and does not show a `ModuleNotFoundError`. I ran the `import pymysql` in it's own cell and it does not throw me back an error, only when I run a job on that notebook do I get an error.

What can be the cause for this?

Comment: https://kb.databricks.com/jobs/job-fails-no-library.html

Comment: @Chris thanks got the libraries to work. Now it's erroring out when it comes to authenticating AWS keys in the notebook so it looks like the environment variables I set for my cluster are not transitioning to the job? Would I set those in the `Parameters` section of the job?